# Iterating through a recordset when returned as an array by a function

Tags: php, mysql

how do you iterate through an array Object that is returned from a PHP function to retrieve all records of a recordset?

Trying to get this piece of code to return an array containing all the rows

```
 // @param group_id @returns result rows of all post from group with the corresponding ID

        function getGroupPostItem($group_id){

      $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE gid = '$group_id'");
   while( $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {



$record_set = array('gid' => $rows['gid'],
                    'pid' => $rows['pid'],
                    'post' => $rows['post'],
                    'filemap_id' => $rows['filemap_id']);


return $record_set;



       }
            }
```

trying to use the below code to print all the record from the rows from the database that matches the query, but all it does is print only one row.

```
$arr = getGroupPostItem('6');
echo $arr['post']. '<br/>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change this line:

```
$record_set = array('gid' => $rows['gid'],
```

... to this:

```
$record_set[] = array('gid' => $rows['gid'],
```

EDIT: also, as stated in the comment by Paul T, `return $record_set;` should be outside the `while` loop.

Note: `echo $arr['post'] . '<br/>';` alone won't display a single value since it's now an array. Instead it would have to be passed through a for or foreach loop. Example:

```
foreach ($arr as $val) {
  echo $val['post'] . '<br/>';
}
```

... or:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
  // Optional, if you want the loop to stop at the 0th value
  if ($i == 0) {
    echo $arr[$i]['post'] . '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: ...and the `return $record_set;` should be outside the while loop?

Comment: keeps throwing an undefined index error! not working out

Comment: @Maxwell: ... after the function returns, add a `var_dump($arr);`, so that you can see how the array information appears.